# Wacom ONE pen tablet driver in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, wacom

Can someone tell me how to install Wacom ONE pen tablet driver in ubuntu 18.04 ?

Comment: 2021: "Our drivers are included in most major Linux distributions and provide out-of-the box support for a wide variety of Wacom tablets and component devices." -- it should work out of the box on the new versions of ubuntu.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

First install the following pre-requisites:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential 
sudo apt-get install autoconf
```

Download and untar input-wacom from [here](https://github.com/linuxwacom/input-wacom/releases)

Move into the directory where your downloaded driver resides and enter the following in the terminal:

```
if test -x ./autogen.sh; then ./autogen.sh; else ./configure; fi && make && sudo make install || echo "Build Failed"
```

To get the verion of the kernel module, enter the following into a terminal:

```
modinfo wacom | grep version
```

Finally update the kernel driver with the following:

```
sudo -s 'apt-get update && apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-wacom'
```

Comment: Thank you so much. The code solved my problem.

Comment: Mine stopped work after that. I've tryed to go through the steps to enable the configuration the the ubuntu settings manager (it didn't appeared there).

Comment: For me, the driver was already installed, but I had to get and compile the latest one for a newer tablet. Also, I had to disable secure boot for the new driver module to load, then it worked well and could be configured via Gnome.

Comment: The accepted answer worked for me as well and note that you have to restart your system. Tried on a wacom one medium!